# TYPO3 tt_products: send a tracking email on status change to admin as well as user

Tags: email, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I use *tt_products 2.7.18* on *TYPO3 6.2.25*.
I configured `orderEmail_to` to the admins email address.

When an order is placed the customer and the admin gets a respective email - as expected.
But when I change the tracking status, only the customer gets an email.

The manual does not tell me how to configure and I'm starting to question the possibility altogether.

Can anyone tell me if and how to configure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> plugin.tt_products {
>
> ...
>
> orderEmail_to = admin@emaildomain.com
>
> ...
>
> }

It is correct to set the orderEmail_to. You should check in the TypoScript Object Browser (backend module Template) that this setup is applied on your tracking page id, where in this example I have given "admin@emaildomain.com" as the admin's email address.

Only the tracking status numbers between 50 and 59 will send a notification email to the customer.

tt_products 2.7.27 is already available. Maybe your version 2.7.18 is already outdated.